# How to construct CFG for language

Tags: context-free

We have alphabet $\Sigma = \{ { a, b} \} $.

How to construct CFG for language $\Sigma^{\ast} - \{a^{n}b^{n} | n \ge 0 \}$.

I suggest that is very easy, but I can't invent. I know PDA for this language if it can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split into parts that you can handle. All strings not of the form $a^*b^*$. All strings of the form $a^ib^j$ with $i< j$. Then all strings ....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PDA for the language can certainly help. The transitions of the PDA can be transformed to production rules. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7AUNNAr060I) is an excellent video on PDA to CFG conversion. 
Let me know if you need any clarification in conversion.